# Jackson - Deserializing JSON into an Object having an Optional field

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, option-type

I have an `Optional<Double>` field which I am trying to deserialize from a JSON, but getting the following Exception:

```
Cannot construct instance of `java.util.Optional`
(although at least one Creator exists):
no BigDecimal/double/Double-argument constructor/factory method
to deserialize from Number value (2.406)
```

*My class:*

```
public final class TestDims implements JsonTyped, Serializable {
    private final Optional<Double> carMeters;
    
    @JsonCreator
    public TestDims(@JsonProperty("carMeters") Optional<Double> carMeters) {
        this.carMeters = carMeters;
    }
    
    @JsonProperty("carMeters")
    public Optional<Double> getCarMeters() {
        return Optional.of(carMeters.orElse(2.2d));
    }
}
```

*Sample JSON:*

```
{
    "carMeters": 2.406
}
```

Comment: Reminder: The Javadoc says: “Optional is primarily intended for use as a method return type…”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Don't use Optional as a field

I would advise getting rid of the Optional.

Firstly, `Optional` **doesn't** implement `Serializable` hence your class is **broken** (because for an object to be serializable, the whole object graph should be serializable).

Secondly, using `Optional` as a field is an antipattern, getters returning an optional are inconvenient, because instead of exposing the actual value they're forcing the caller to deal with an Optional.

A possible solution is to change the type of `carMeters` to `double`:

```
public final class TestDims implements JsonTyped, Serializable {
    public static final double DEFAULT_METERS = 2.2;
    
    private final double carMeters;
    
    @JsonCreator
    public TestDims(@JsonProperty("carMeters") double carMeters) {
        this.carMeters = carMeters == 0 ? DEFAULT_METERS : carMeters;
    }
    
    @JsonProperty("carMeters")
    public double getCarMeters() {
        return carMeters;
    }
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String json1 = """
        {
            "carMeters": 2.406
        }""";

    String json2 = """
        {
            "carMeters": null
        }""";

    String json3 = """
        {   }
        """;
    
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    
    System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json1, TestDims.class));
    System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json2, TestDims.class));
    System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json3, TestDims.class));
}
```

*Output:*

```
TestDims{carMeters=2.406} // a regular value
TestDims{carMeters=2.2}   // provided value is null
TestDims{carMeters=2.2}   // the property is not present
```

## If you still want to use Optional

If you want to use Optional as a field at all costs, then your class would not be serializable. There's no workaround.

To let the Jackson know how to deal with Optional, you would need to add a dependency for [Jackson Datatype: JDK8 module](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8), and register it.

If you're not using any framework, then you would need to register the module manually using `ObjectMapper.registerModule()` before deserializing JSON.

With Spring Boot, it would be sufficient to add this module to the Spring's Context by using a method annotated with `@Bean`.

```
@Bean
public Jdk8Module jdk8Module() {
    return new Jdk8Module();
}
```

And it would be registered automatically while configuring `ObjectMapper`.

Also **note**, that it doesn't make sense to use `Optional<Double>` since there's a type `OptionalDouble` wrapping a primitive.

```
public final static class TestDimsss implements JsonTyped {
    public static final OptionalDouble DEFAULT_METERS = OptionalDouble.of(2.2D);
    private final OptionalDouble carMeters;
    
    @JsonCreator
    public TestDimsss(@JsonProperty("carMeters") OptionalDouble carMeters){
        this.carMeters = carMeters;
    }
    
    @JsonProperty("carMeters")
    public OptionalDouble getCarMeters() {
        return carMeters.isPresent() ? carMeters : DEFAULT_METERS;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TestDimsss{" +
            "carMeters=" + carMeters +
            '}';
    }
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String json1 = """
        {
            "carMeters": 2.406
        }""";

    String json2 = """
        {
            "carMeters": null
        }""";

    String json3 = """
        {   }
        """;
    
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
    
    System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json1, TestDims.class));
    System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json2, TestDims.class));
    System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json3, TestDims.class));
}
```

*Output:*

```
TestDimsss{carMeters=OptionalDouble[2.406]}  // a regular value
TestDimsss{carMeters=OptionalDouble.empty}   // provided value is null
TestDimsss{carMeters=OptionalDouble.empty}   // the property is not present
```